# Using Sage Math library within Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sage

I am trying to make a visualization of a graph using Sage. I need to make the visualization exactly as I am writing the Python code.

I have downloaded and installed the Sage for Ubuntu and Sage Notebook is working perfectly. But I want to take user input from Tkinter and then show those input on the Graph (generated by Sage). However, I am unable to import sage in the Python Shell. How can I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From looking at the [faq](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/faq/faq-usage.html#how-do-i-import-sage-into-a-python-script), it looks like what you need to do is add the following line to your Python file:

```
from sage.all import *
```

Then, it looks like you need to run your script by using the Python interpreter bundled with Sage from the command line/console:

```
sage -python /path/to/my/script.py
```

However, if you want to use Sage directly from the shell, you should probably try using the [interactive shell](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/interactive_shell.html). (just type in `sage` or maybe `sage -python` from the command line)

Caveat: I haven't tested any of this myself, so you might need to do a bit of experimenting to get everything to work.

Comment: Using `sage -ipython` is particularly nice for this.

Comment: kcrisman the Problem was not using root.mainloop() [root declared as root = Tk()].